# Hook function prints output twice

Tags: hooks

I have started learning Hooks today and trying to accomplish the following.

When the home page of my site loads, it would insert a new term in my custom taxonomy called `amenities`. Then using a dynamic Hook (`create_{$taxonomy}`, in my case it is `create_amenities`) and with the help of a custom function hooked into `create_amenities` I am printing the newly added `term_id`.

This is what I did

**1. Created a function to print the new term_id, which accepts one parameter and hooked it into above.**

```
add_action('create_amenities', 'tourplan_print_new_amenity_term_id', 10, 1);

function tourplan_print_new_amenity_term_id($term_id) {
   // Printing twice while should only print once.
   echo 'The newly added term id is: '. $term_id;
}
```

**2. Inside my index.php I have written the following:**

```
$arr_term = array(
  'description' => 'Honeymoon Suit for couple',
  'slug'        => 'honeymoon-suite'
)

$new_term = $wp_insert_term('Honeymoon Suit', 'amenities', $arr_term);
$new_term_id = $new_term['term_id'];

do_action('create_amenities', $new_term_id);
```

**3. And finally I am removing the term from taxonomy after calling above `do_action` method:**

```
wp_remove_term($new_term_id, 'amenities');
```

Everything works fine except the Hook function is printing the value of ID twice. What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am not using any ready made theme or any child theme. It is a completely hand-built theme from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add `do_action('create_amenities', $new_term_id);`.

The [created_{$taxonomy}](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/) hook fires after a new term in a specific taxonomy is created by default.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I understand now. Is there any way to know whether an associated hook is firing automatically when something is done like this? Can you please suggest a place where I can read more about it?

Comment: Just refer to the official code reference when in doubt of how any hook works: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/created_taxonomy/